# TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER black screen

Tags: webgl

I got always black screen for `TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER != world.GL.gl.NEAREST`

```js
       world.GL.gl.activeTexture(world.GL.gl['TEXTURE' + t]);
       world.GL.gl.bindTexture(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D, object.textures[t]);
       world.GL.gl.pixelStorei(world.GL.gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, false);

       if (world.GL.extTFAnisotropic) {
            world.GL.gl.texParameterf(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D,
              world.GL.extTFAnisotropic.TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT,
              world.GL.MAX_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT);
          }
          
       world.GL.gl.texParameteri(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D, world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, object.texParams.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER | world.GL.gl.LINEAR);
       world.GL.gl.texParameteri(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D, world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, object.texParams.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER | world.GL.gl.LINEAR);
       world.GL.gl.texParameteri(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D, world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, object.texParams.TEXTURE_WRAP_S | world.GL.gl.REPEAT);
       world.GL.gl.texParameteri(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D, world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, object.texParams.TEXTURE_WRAP_T | world.GL.gl.REPEAT);
 
           
       world.GL.gl.uniform1i(object.shaderProgram.samplerUniform, t);
```

### WORKS:

gl.LINEAR, gl.NEAREST,

### NOT WORKS:

gl.NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST, gl.NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR.

Also if i use generate mipmap then i cant use TEXTURE_WRAP_S ...

Comment: If object.texParams.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER is not passed by args then use LINEAR nothing else

Answer (score 1):

In [WebGL 1.0](https://registry.khronos.org/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/), if you want to use a mipmap filter, the size of the texture (width and height) must be a power of 2 (also see [OpenGL ES 2.0 Full Specification](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.pdf#page=93&zoom=100,168,173)). Either make the size of the textures a power of 2 or switch to [WebGL 2.0](https://registry.khronos.org/webgl/specs/latest/2.0/) (OpenGL ES 3.0) where this restriction does not apply.

Comment: I added generateMipmap and removed `TEXTURE_WRAP_x` and works nice !

Comment: I still get `WebGL warning: generateMipmap: The texture's base level must be complete.` but draws works fine